# Azure DevOps Build From Subversion

Tags: svn, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a build in Azure DevOps Pipeline that has subversion as the code source.

There seems to be a problem with the build agent. The error is as follows.

```
##[Error 1]
No agent found in pool Hosted VS2017 which satisfies the specified demands:
     svn
```

The build agent (Hosted VS2017) does have subversion installed - the following is in the details for the pool.

```
Subversion
Version: 1.8.17<br/>
Environment:

PATH: contains location of svn.exe
```

I am not sure where the problem is. Any help welcome.

Comment: Different build agents have different things installed. If it works with "Hosted VS2017", what is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. That's the problem. Even though SVN is installed I get the error.

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally read that wrong. Yeah, that doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: No worries Dan. Thanks for taking the time to look. I figured this out last night but only have my phone to add replies. I'll post a full answer when I am back at my desk later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the capability for svn was not explicitly defined on the agent.

The agent must have a capability that matches the demand in order for the build to run. The agent did have Subversion installed, but that is not enough. There must be an entry in the capabilities table that defines it to the build system.

The answer is to manually add that entry as a 'user capability' as shown below:

[image: DevOps svn Capability]

Comment: Thank you, @Mark. How did you find this out? Is there a list of supported capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

This fix for this issue is rolling out. You no longer need to add a "svn" user capability to hosted agents. Apologies for the inconvenience.